# SQL Daily Outstanding Sales, Rolling Aggregate?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

With the below test data I am trying to show how many sales have not been actioned by a colleague, an outstanding sale is any record that is still showing as "New", I have been using the below to identify those.

```
select saleID, count(*) group by saleID having count(*)=1
```

The trouble I have is that I find it easy to show **overall** how many are still outstanding **to date** but I can't figure out how to show how many were outstanding say 3 days ago. The idea is that this will show a trend when charted daily which will highlight if there has been an increase/decrease of outstanding sales by the end of each day. Ideally the output would be along the lines of the below

```
   Date      VolumeOutstanding 
2020-01-01    0
2020-01-02    1
2020-01-03    3
2020-01-04    2
```

**DataSet**

```
SaleID   Date         Outcome
1        2020-01-01   New
1        2020-01-01   Complete
2        2020-01-01   New
2        2020-01-02   Complete
3        2020-01-03   New
4        2020-01-03   New
5        2020-01-03   New
5        2020-01-04   Complete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation and a cumulative sum:

```
select date,
       sum(sum(case when outcome = 'New' then 1
                    when outcome  'Complete' then -1
                    else 0
               end)
           ) over (order by date) as VolumeOutstanding
from t
group by date
order by date;
```

This assumes that each `saleId` has at most one "new" and one "complete" record -- which makes sense and is true in your sample data.

Comment: Thanks this is amazing, not that familiar with window functions used in this way, generally I use them with row numbers so will look into this

Comment: one other aspect I can't figure out was how long it has been outstanding i.e. <24 hours, <48 hours etc....I would normally use Now() but if I then run that the next day my previous results will be affected

Comment: @Chris . . . You should ask a new question with appropriate sample data and desired results.