# SQL How Long Have Incomplete Records Been Outstanding Broken Down By Day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have asked a similar question to this [SQL Daily Outstanding Sales, Rolling Aggregate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61797669/sql-daily-outstanding-sales-rolling-aggregate/61798663?noredirect=1#comment109312390_61798663) however I now need to understand, by day, how long sales have been outstanding. This will be grouped into 24 hours (or day) intervals to a max of 72hours. An example of the output from the Dataset is below, Timeoutstanding would be within a group by however Date needs to be *any* date, even if it was not within the DataSet which can be seen with 2020-01-02 on the second row

```
Date         TimeOutstanding    VolumeOutstanding  
2020-01-01   Under24Hour        1                                   
2020-01-02   Under48Hour        1
2020-01-03   Under24Hour        3
2020-01-03   Under72Hour        1
2020-01-04   Under48Hour        3
2020-01-05   Under72Hour        2
2020-01-05   Over72Hour         1
```

DataSet

```
SaleID   Date         Outcome
1        2020-01-01   New
1        2020-01-01   Complete
2        2020-01-01   New
3        2020-01-03   New
4        2020-01-03   New
5        2020-01-03   New
2        2020-01-04   Complete
5        2020-01-04   Complete
3        2020-01-06   Complete
4        2020-01-07   Complete
```

Comment: Have you made any further attempts to amend the prior answer you got to get the new results you are after? What were those attempt(s)? Why didn't they work?

Comment: I did adapt the solution that was given in the previous answer to close of a few other issues I was having but this particular one I can't figure out because of the use of getDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can summarize each salesid with the new and completed date.  Then, generate the dates that you care about.  And use conditional aggregation:

```
select d.date,
       count(*) as num_open,
       sum(case when new_date >= dateadd(day, -1, d) then 1 else 0
           end) as within_1day,
       sum(case when new_date < dateadd(day, -1, d)  and new_date >= dateadd(day, -3, d then 1 else 0
           end) as within_1_3days_ago,
       . . .
from (select distinct date from t) d left join
     (select salesid, min(date) as new_date,
             nullif(max(date), min(date)) as completed_date
      from t
      group by salesid
     ) t
     on new_date <= date and (date < completed_date or completed_date is null)
group by d.date
```

Comment: what about the situation when the table does not contain a date, in the above the date 2020-01-02 doesn't exist but there was still 1 outstanding sale on that day. The date could be missing as no actions (i.e. no new or completed entries) took place that day

Comment: @Chris . . . Replace the `d` subquery with the list of dates that you want -- either an explicit list using `values()` or from another table or perhaps generated through a recursive CTE.